# Regular Expression to remove space from lines starting with specific string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ and I'm trying to edit objects from a script that have spaces in them.  The specific lines would start with "edit".

```
edit test-object-1
set subnet 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
next
edit test-object-2
set subnet 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
next
edit test object 3
set subnet 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
next
edit test-object-4
set subnet 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
next
edit test-object-5
set subnet 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
```

What I would like to do is replace the spaces in "test object 3" to "test-object-3"

So far it seems that I would start with something like ''' "^edit\s" ''' but I'm getting stuck at being able to search only words that contain a \s between words.  Any help on finding and replacing in notepad would be appreciated and I'm sure it's something simple too :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
 (?:\G(?!^)|^edit\h)\S*\K\h+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `^edit\h` match edit at the start of the string followed by a horizontal whitespace char (according to the comment)
- `)` Close group
- `\S*` Match 0+ non whitespace chars
- `\K\h+` Clear the match buffer (forget what is matched until now) and match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QYQ8eU/1)

In the replacement use `-`

[image]

Comment: In sequential matching patterns like this, the `(?:^edit|\G(?!^))` is better written as `(?:\G(?!^)|^edit)` because `^edit` will only be matched once and `\G(?!^)` is assumed to be matched more than once. Both will match the same text, but the latter will probably make fewer steps to accomplish the task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, this solution adds a - after the edit, creating edit-test-object which wouldn't work.

But as I was typing that, I added a \s after the edit in your code and that seems to be the solution.

(?:^edit\s|\G(?!^))\S*\K\h+

Thank you!!

Comment: @purge123 Ok, I have updated matching a horizontal whitespace char after edit as `\s` might also match a newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, it is indeed less steps. I see you writing it it that order often. Is that because it is at the left side of the alternation?

Comment: Alternations are tested from left to right, and the first one that matches stop the regex parser from checking the remaining alternatives. That is why it makes more sense to place `\G(?!^)` as the first alternative since it will match more often (ideally).